# Calculating values for Cross Matrix table in Power BI DAX

Tags: matrix, powerbi, measure, cross-correlation

I have the following table, which shows how many MH(Mental Health type) and/or SA (Substance Abuse type) diagnosis for a particular client:

For, example - Client with the ClientID = 22 has 2 diagnosis category (MH and SA); while ClientID = 23 has only 1 diagnosis category (SA)

Diagnosis:

```
     Client_ID  Diagnosis_Desc  Diagnosis_Cat
     22         Bi-Polar        MH
     22         Alcohol         SA
     23         Cocaine         SA
     24         Scizophrenia    MH
     24         Alcohol         SA
     25         Nicotine        SA
     25         PTSD            MH
     25         Stress          MH
```

I also have measure, which calculates number of Diagnosis_Cat (Diagnosis category) per client:

So, if I populate my data with [# Category per Client] measure, it'll look as:

```
     Client_ID  Diagnosis_Desc  Diagnosis_Cat  [# Category per Client]
     22         Bi-Polar        MH              2
     22         Alcohol         SA              2
     23         Cocaine         SA              1
     24         Scizophrenia    MH              2
     24         Alcohol         SA              2
     25         Nicotine        SA              2
     25         PTSD            MH              2
     25         Stress          MH              2
```

My goal is to create a Cross Matrix table, where

X = SA diagnosis,

Y = MH diagnosis,

value = # of Clients that have SA-MH diagnosis pair (crossed pair).

This is the measure for my value:

```
     # Dual Diagnosed Clients = CALCULATE(
                                DISTINCTCOUNT('Diagnosis'[ClientID]),
                                 FILTER(
                                   'Diagnosis',
                                   'Diagnosis'[# Category per Client] = 2
        
                                  )
                                  )
```

I also created 2 tables with MH and SA unduplicated data and throwing them into my Matrix - Attrib_1 and Attrib_2

So, the visual looks like (shows total # of unduplicated, dually diagnosed (MH-SA) clients)-

[image]

While I expected to see in this cross-matrix -

Alcohol-Bi-Polar = 1 Client (ClientID 22);

Alcohol-PTSD = 0 Clients (or just an empty cell)

Alcohol-Scizophrenia = 1 Client (ClientID 24),  etc.

Plz, help to adjust my measure.

Comment: Can you paste data as text?

Comment: @David  Ok, just updated my data - copy-pasted into the post

Comment: @Hell-1931 The cell where Bi-Polar and Alcohol are intersected has no meaning. A cell can't have both Bi-Polar and Alcohol at the same time. An empty row and empty column is inserted into the resulting visual.